# Magento get function trough php

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get some data from Magento trough php, it works but I need to add multiple collections and now I am stuck. I am just a beginner so please forgive me :-)

I am using below code to get customer details, this works ok.
Now I need to add the customer/address to get the address details to fill the last column with the zipcode, anybody know how to do that?

```
<?php
function getcustomers() {
    /* Magento's Mage.php path
     * Mage Enabler users may skip these lines
     */
    require_once ("app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    Mage::app("nl");
    /* Magento's Mage.php path */

    /* Get customer model, run a query */
  $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    //$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $customer) {
        $result[] = $customer->toArray();
    }

    return $result;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Customers</title>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Is Active?</td>
    <td>Date Created</td>
    <td>Date Updated</td>
    <td>Website ID</td>
    <td>Store ID</td>
    <td>Zip Code</td>
</tr>
<?php
$result = getcustomers();
if(count($result) > 0){
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$value['entity_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['lastname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['firstname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $value['is_active'] == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['created_at']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['updated_at']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['website_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['store_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['zipcode']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\">No records found</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to say that I'm currently learning Magento, so my answer will not be totally working! I hope it'll help to push you in the right direction.

Just a note, you can just use `$customer->getData()` to return an array.

Then you can use `$customer->getId()` to get the id. Which you can then pass into the Address model

```
foreach($collection as $customer){
  // You have an instance of the Customer already, so we can just use a magic get method
  $cid = $customer->getId();

  // Let's load this customers address, using a chain. Load the model (instantiate the class), then call load with the customer id
  // You might want to check the alias on 'customer' to ensure it has address. You can find this in /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml ln.251
  $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($cid);
  // Maybe we should look in here just in case - for debugging
  var_dump($address); // or echo get_class($address);
  // Here I would try one of the magic setter methods, which map to set<Thing> so you can play with this to see if it'll work
  $address->setZipCode('12345');
  // Then we should be able to save it, I think, this bit I'm not sure on.
  $address->save();
}
```

As I say, this is just what I've learnt from the Magento U videos over the last week, hope it works!

Comment: You are right but you don't need to use `$customer->getData()` at all, you just need to use the customer object and then `$customer->getId()` and you could just use `$customer->getAddresses()` and get any addresses they may have.

Comment: @VernBurton Ah I see, I wasn't sure if Address was part of Customer or not :)

Comment: @DavidYll - have you seen the developer coursed in Magento U?

Comment: @VernBurton Yes, I'm in the middle of it at the moment, 'Section 3 - Request Flow, Lesson 5' to be exact :)

Comment: Thanks for all the reactions, I think this is going above my head :-) Maybe one simple question then, how can I get data from two collections on the same page? I need it from both address and customer $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
  $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')

Comment: @SandervanZuidam I answered this on your OTHER question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236485/get-data-from-two-models-in-one-page-magento