# Get data from two models in one page - Magento

Tags: php, magento

Could someone help me with the following two questions?

1. How can I filter on Websiteid in the query below?
2. Is it possible to get data out of two collections in one file? The last value "company" should come from the customer address model which is now commented out.

```php
<?php function getcustomers() 
{
  /* Magento's Mage.php path
   * Mage Enabler users may skip these lines
   */
  require_once ("app/Mage.php");
  umask(0);
  Mage::app("nl");
  /* Magento's Mage.php path */

  /* Get customer model, run a query */
  $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
  //$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  $result = array();
  foreach ($collection as $customer) { $result[] = $customer->toArray();  }

  return $result; 
} 
?>
```

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Customers</title>
  <style>    table {border-collapse: collapse;} 
  td {padding: 5px;   border:1px              solid             #000000;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Lastname</td>
<td>Firstname</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Is Active?</td>
<td>Date Created</td>
<td>Date Updated</td>
<td>Website ID</td>
<td>Store ID</td>
<td>Zip Code</td>
</tr>
<?php
   $result = getcustomers();
   if(count($result) > 0)
   {
     foreach($result as $key => $value)
     {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$value['entity_id']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['lastname']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['firstname']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['email']."</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $value['is_active'] == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['created_at']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['updated_at']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['website_id']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['store_id']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$value['zipcode']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }
   }
   else
   {
     echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\">No records found</td></tr>";
   }
   ?>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, maybe try this? Again I'm not sure if this will work, but I think its in the right direction.

```
<?php 

$collection1 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection();

$merged_ids = array_merge($collection1->getAllIds(), $collection2->getAllIds());

$merged_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $merged_ids)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter();


?>
```